# How to set FPS 60 câmera in Adobe AIR (ActionScript 3.0)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I'm trying to get the best resolution of my webcam câmera (Logitech BRIO 4k). It only returns at max 30 fps.

```
cam.setQuality(16384, 100);
cam.setMode(1920, 1080, 60, true);
cam.setKeyFrameInterval(1);
```

Specs from Logitech: 4K Ultra HD video calling (up to 4096 x 2160 pixels @ 30 fps)
1080p Full HD video calling (up to 1920 x 1080 pixels @ 30 or 60 fps)
720p HD video calling (up to 1280 x 720 pixels @ 30, 60, or 90 fps)

Comment: Shot in the dark: is your SWF running at 60? The default setting is 30fps i believe. [Adobe's guide on Application FPS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a61c0b0b612763986266-8000.html)

Comment: Make sure you have added the following meta [SWF(width="1920", height="1080", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#000000")] in your main class. Also replace the backgroundColor with your desired color and the width and height with your app width and height.

Comment: @DodgerThud  Yes, in the properties I am setting to 60 FPS. I think the problem is with the camera. I could force it to capture 60 FPS (bitmapData). But I loose quality when using the camera that could get higher quality.

When I trace the cam.fps it returns me always 30 as value.

Comment: @ConstantinStan Yes, didn't solved the problem. :(

Comment: And using : `cam.setMode(1280, 720, 60, true);` doesn't work? Also what's your AIR SDK version? Is this AIR making a Windows app?